# Node.js + MongoDB methods insertOne or insert issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, mongodb

I have this issue with node.js and mongodb.
I followed the example from [mongodb.github.io](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/crud/), '

the code is:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
assert = require('assert');

// Connection url   
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

// Use connect method to connect to server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('Connected to server');

    // Insert a single document
    db.collection('test').insertOne({a:1}, function(err, r){
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);
    });
});
```

in my console i get the following error:

```
Object #Collection has no method 'insertOne'.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the version of mongodb?

Comment: I did npm update mongodb, now using driver version 2.1.18, but still the same, from mongo console I can use insertOne(), and other methods just fine, but from app.js using node got same error

Comment: Weird, your code works fine when I try it with 2.1.18. You may not be using the version of the driver that you think you are. I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: Yes you are right. it was a driver, I did **npm uninstall mongodb** and **npm uninstall mongoose**, after that install them again and only then it works. Thanks for your help everyone.